# Vertically center the content of some cell in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

[image]I'm writing a research paper in latex and I'm having trouble formatting a table. I'm making a full-page table and I can't figure out how to vertically center the contents of some cells. This question has been asked several times, but I've tried to implement the solutions presented in other situations, and nothing works.
Please take a look at my code and the output of it.
Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[legalpaper, margin=0.7in]{geometry} 
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,columnsep=1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \addlinespace
    \begin{tabular}{p{3.11em}cp{3.52em}p{3.16em}p{2.89em}p{4.945em}p{3.055em}p{3.8em}p{3em}p{2.67em}p{3.4em}}
  \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Author (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.72em}}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Publi-cation Date}}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Market}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Period Studied}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Input Data}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Predictor Technique}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Best Predictor}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Perfor-mance Metrics }} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Trading Strategy}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Causal Relationship}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\textbf{Profita-bility Metrics}} \\
    \midrule
    \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{\cite{1}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{2021} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{American, Forex} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{2018-2020} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{HPD, 2xTI} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{XGBoost} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{-} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{Accuracy} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{Yes} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{-} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .247,  .361}{Yes} \\
    \midrule
    \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{\cite{3}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{2019} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{American} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{2017-2019} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{HPD, TI} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{GCN + Graph Based Linear model + ARIMA} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{Graph Based Linear model} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{MAPE, RMSE, MAE} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{-} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{Yes} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .404,  .592}{-} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Which cells should be vertically centred?

Comment: Thanks @Bernard! For example, in the first row the ones that say "Author(s)" and "Market", etc. Then on the third row all of them except the one that says "GCN + Graph Based Linear model + ARIMA"

Comment: You have two possibilities: either each of the `p{some length}` with `m{some length}` (in which cases all cells will be vertically centred) or load the `makecell` package and use its eponymous command, which yields cells which are vertically & horizontally centred by default.